# ListFieldIterator postback issue

Tags: custom-form

I have strange behavior of ListFieldIterator in SharePoint 2013. I create custom template for my list in CONTROLTEMPLATES folder, copy default template and add button that does post back (the event handler of this button is empty). Then I deploy solution, open my list and see this form. I fill fields and click on added button (test). After postback some of the field is cleared. What I missed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the SharePoint 2013 uses a new rendering templates for fields and this templates have a couple of bugs. How to solve bugs for a note and a boolean fields look [here](http://spsite.pro/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=8).